# Is a generic List stored contiguously in memory

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

There are various articles, for instance msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx, which seem to suggest that the items of a generic List are stored in contiguous memory. However I can't find any definitive statement to that effect either way. Does anyone know of one. Note that it is very clearly stated that arrays are contiguous but this question applies to List.

Also is there any way to access the memory used by a List directly?

Comment: I think you'll need to call ToArray() on the generic list in order to begin accessing it's memory directly.

Answer (score 7):

The source of [List<T>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) is quite explicit:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;

    private T[] _items;
```

a `List<T>` contains an array of `T` (`T[]`), so if the array is contiguous (yes, it is), then `List<T>` is contiguous :-)

And from the [List<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) MSDN page:

> The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. **It implements the IList generic interface by using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required**.

For the second question:

> Also is there any way to access the memory used by a List directly?

You seem to be more a "theoretical" programmer, so the answer is no. To the "practical" programmers that are reading this, they can use:

```
public static class ArrayFromList
{
    public static FieldInfo GetField<T>()
    {
        return ArrayFromListImpl<T>.Field;
    }

    public static T[] GetArray<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        return ArrayFromListImpl<T>.GetArray(list);
    }

    public static class ArrayFromListImpl<T>
    {
        public static readonly FieldInfo Field;

        public static readonly Func<List<T>, T[]> GetArray;

        static ArrayFromListImpl()
        {
            Field = typeof(List<T>)
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(T[]))
                .Single();

            var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<T>));
            var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>, T[]>>(Expression.Field(par, Field), par);
            GetArray = exp.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
var lst = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var ptr = ArrayFromList.GetArray(lst);
```

Note that this won't work on a "theretical" `List<T>` that "hides" the array in a sub-object :-) (but will work on .NET and Mono :-) )

Comment: Yes but that is a current implementation detail not a guarantee at the public interface level.

Comment: @goneskiing Better now? Note that this is C#, not C++. The .NET libraries don't have a pedantic description of all their characteristics. They are more "this is the Microsoft .NET... Be happy"

Comment: Note that if `T` is a reference type, the handles will be contiguous in memory but the actual objects won't be.

Comment: Actually I'm not really theoretical! I have some code that pin_ptr's .NET array data and passes the pointer to some unmanaged C++ code to avoid a fairly big memory copy. I have some code I can't change that gives me a List not an Array so I wanted to do the same. I like your code. Not being a C# person I assume this is using reflection to find the _items member variable?

Comment: Note I only do this if the types are blittable of course

Comment: @goneskiing It is using reflection to find an array, that in the Microsoft implementation is named `_items` :-) Then it is using some tricks to cache this array accessing, so that reflection is used only once for each type of `List<T>`, and successive uses don't use it. **and remember that the array could be bigger than the `Count` of the `List<T>`!**